# Is the timer being started from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

[QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) documentation suggests two ways to make code run in a separate thread. If I subclass QThread and reimplement run(), then I get

```
QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread
```

-

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QThread>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class Worker : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int id;
    bool m_abort = false;
    bool compute = false;
public:
    Worker() {}

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) override {
        if (event->timerId() == id) {
            compute = true;
        } else {
            QObject::timerEvent(event);
        }
    }
public slots:
    void abort() {m_abort = true;}
    void run() {
        qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
        QBasicTimer timer;
        id = timer.timerId();
        timer.start(1000, this);
        forever {
            if (m_abort) break;
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
            if (compute)
                qDebug() << "computed";
            compute = false;
        }
    }
};

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread thread;
    Worker* worker;
public:
    MainWidget()
    {
        qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
        worker = new Worker;
        worker->start();
    }
    ~MainWidget(){worker->abort();}
};
```

1) Is the timer being started from another thread?
 2) Why I don't get that warning when QBasicTimer is replaced by QTimer?
 3) Why I don't get that warning when using moveToThread?

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QThread>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QBasicTimer* timer;
    bool m_abort = false;
    bool compute = false;
public:
    Worker() {}

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) override {
        if (event->timerId() == timer->timerId()) {
            compute = true;
        } else {
            QObject::timerEvent(event);
        }
    }
public slots:
    void abort() {m_abort = true;}
    void run() {
        timer = new QBasicTimer;
        timer->start(1000, this);
        forever {
            if (m_abort) break;
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
            if (compute)
                qDebug() << "computed";
            compute = false;
        }
    }
};

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread thread;
    Worker* worker;
public:
    MainWidget()
    {
        worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&thread);
        connect(this, &MainWidget::start, worker, &Worker::run);
        thread.start();
        emit start();
    }
    ~MainWidget(){worker->abort(); thread.quit(); thread.wait();}
signals:
    void start();
};
```

Comment: You constructed the timer with no parent, so it won't get moved when the worker is moved to its thread.

Comment: You mean the QBasicTimer timer? May I ask how should I contruct it?

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't think so, the timer is created at the beginning of the `run()` function and destroyed at the end. So it does not even exist when `moveToThread()` is called. I think the issue is that it is not possible to catch the timeout of a timer from another thread than the one from where it is started (same thing to stop it).

Comment: @KcFnMi In your moveToThread example, the `run()` function creates a timer, starts it and exit immediately after (which will destroy the timer by the way).

Comment: Moreover, to start a timer in another thread, you need to execute an event loop on the corresponding thread too otherwise you'll never receive timer events.

Comment: Agree with these things, though I'm not complaing about the moveToThread approach. The other approach that intrigues me.

Comment: The other approach has the same issues. I should not have written _"In your moveToThread example"_ but _"In your examples"_ instead.

Comment: The other approach does have an event loop, right? It's not necessary to call exec(). Just replace QBasicTimer by QTimer and it works as I expect.

Comment: No, `run()` will be called in another thread. In this thread, you have to run your own event loop (with `QThread::exec()`). But keep in mind that you can't get the timeout neither stop the timer from another thread too.

Comment: I really doubt it works, perhaps it is not complaining, but your `run()` exits immediately and your `QTimer` is destroyed likewise. But even if it were not, you'll receive no events without an event loop. You should take a look at [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html) and [that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details). This is the Qt documentation that states what I'm trying to say. It will help you to solve what's wrong :)

Comment: Are you saying in the moveToThread approach it is necessary to call QObject::exec to have an event loop? I think in thtat approach is automatic, no need to call it, if I replace QBasicTimer by QTimer it works here, without caliing exec().

Comment: AFAIK, it is not automatic. To start an event loop and enter event handling, you have to call `QThread::exec()` from the `run()` function. You should take a look at the `QThread` documentation too :) To be honest, the Qt documentation is very informative and helpful. Moreover, if the program is not complaining, it does not mean that it works as expected at all. Just try to connect something to your timeout or stop your timer, you'll get nothing ;)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misread your comment, I was talking for the non-moveToThread approach. But for the moveToThread approach, you'll have an event handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the first (non-`moveToThread`) example...

A quick look at the Qt source for [`QBasicTimer::start`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbasictimer.html#start) shows the following...

```
void QBasicTimer::start(int msec, QObject *obj)
{
    QAbstractEventDispatcher *eventDispatcher = QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance();

    // ...

    if (Q_UNLIKELY(obj && obj->thread() != eventDispatcher->thread())) {
        qWarning("QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread");
        return;
    }
```

So it expects its second argument `obj` to have a thread affinity equal to the current thread.

In your `Worker::run` implementation, however, you have...

```
timer.start(1000, this);
```

In this context the current thread is the new thread created by the `QThread` instance but `this` refers to the `QWorker` instance created by the `MainWidget` on the main GUI thread.  Hence the warning.

**Edit 1:**

To the question...

> why it works with moveToThread()?

Consider the implementation of the `MainWidget` ctor...

```
MainWidget()
{
    worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(this, &MainWidget::start, worker, &Worker::run);
    thread.start();
    emit start();
}
```

By the time `Worker::run` is called the `Worker` instance has been moved to the new thread.  So when the line...

```
timer.start(1000, this);
```

executes, `this` (which refers to the `Worker` instance) is on the current thread and the thread affinity test in `QBasicTimer::start` passes without warning.

Sorry if the above is a bit convoluted but the important thing is to consider the thread affinity of the second arg to `QBasicTimer::start`: it *must* be the currently running thread.

Comment: I'm already in a `QObject` context (I mean already doing `#include <QObject>`) anyway so I should use `QTimer` instead of `QBasicTimer`. Should I think this way?

Comment: @G.M: Could you clarify more about the question (3) : why it works with moveToThread() ?

Comment: @tunglt Updated the answer.

Comment: @KcFnMi If you want a timer that can be used to issue timeout notifications between different threads then, yes, I'd use `QTimer`.

Comment: I'm concerned about timeout notifications on the timer thread (not between threads). Should I expect better performance using `QBasicTimer` even in a context like that?

Comment: @KcFnMi What do you mean by performance here?  Unless you're working in a hard realtime environment then, generally speaking, all timers will have a certain amount of jitter/latency with no guarantees being given.  If you have specific requirements in that respect then that would probably warrant a separate question.